# i cant get the firebase display each data on each cardview of my android app but it shows same data on every cardview

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database

[this is my firebase data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygriS.png)

It's the code which I have done, but it only shows the same data again and again from the firebase database. On the cardview the last key value pair is showing from the data.

Here is the main problem

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Textobj textobj = null;
           for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               textobj = new Textobj(data.getKey().toString(),  data.getValue().toString());
               arrayList.add(position,textobj);
           }
           textView.setText(arrayList.get(position).getMtext().toString());
      textView1.setText(arrayList.get(position).getMtext2().toString());
           }


 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 Log.w((String) TAG, "Failed to read                                                                                       value.",databaseError.toException());
     }
   });
   }
 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
  int size = value2.length;
    return size;
      }
       }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the data exact you want to get.

Comment: i have added the link above

Comment: i have added the data structure link above

Answer (score 0):

To get the data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference foodRef = rootRef.child("food");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", key + " / "  + value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
foodRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
Ktm / American made super bike...
Pulse / this is the indian made...
Yamaha / japan made super bike...
```

Comment: now also it is only showing the last key and value on every cardview yamaha and its value on every card

Comment: What is the output in yor logcat?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved i  added the values i got to my Textobj class and added it to the arraylist and got it right
the code is given below

```
 ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              String key = data.getKey();
               String value = data.getValue(String.class);
              Textobj textobj = new Textobj(key,value);
              arrayList1.add(textobj);
              textView.setText(arrayList1.get(position).getMtext());
              textView1.setText(arrayList1.get(position).getMtext2());

          }
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Log.w((String) TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
      }
  };
   myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);


}
```

Comment: now  i can get each value on each cardview from my database